# SQLite FTS3 and building for iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Can I use SQLite's FTS3 when building for the iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use SQLite's FTS3 when building for the iPhone and iPad. This [tutorial](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/06/16/sqlite-full-text-search-for-iphone-ipadyour-own-sqlite-for-iphone-and-ipad/) may help.

Comment: Even though FTS3 is not enabled by default? eg. I need to import a copy of SQLite3 - how do I build for FTS3 in my project?

Comment: @SK9: Yes. Check out the linked tutorial for installation directions.