# Using PhoneGap 3.1, which database storage option for full-text search?

Tags: sqlite, text, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to PhoneGap, and to programming with database storage in general. I have searched & read many articles & StackOverflow questions detailing different methods of integrating a database with a PhoneGap app, but most are written for earlier versions of PhoneGap, and address different uses to the ones my app needs. My app needs:

1) To ship pre-populated with text records.

2) To offer pre-indexed full-text search of these records.

I am using PhoneGap 3.1, which according to the [API documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) has two built-in database methods: Web Storage, and Web SQL Database. The [PhoneGap SQLite](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin) is also recommended in many articles, but I haven't found any references to people using it with PhoneGap 3.1.

Can anyone suggest which database option I am better off focusing on to perform the functions needed, or any introductory articles that would explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with using the [PhoneGap SQLite](https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin) plugin, as the full text search is available only on the native side.

Additionally, on iOS you have to compile SQLite with full text search [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313521/sqlite-fts3-and-building-for-ios).